How to re-achieve the effect made by negative math nodes

Recently there was an update to blender that ended up breaking one of my shaders, the update made sure we dont get negative inputs for closure nodes which I need in order to make the shader work as intended.

This is how its supposed to look and was how it looked From up to 4.0.2

This is how it looks after the 4.1.1 update

This is the whole general node set up

This is the setup of the node group (Identical aside from color but this is Nodegroup .007)
Is there any way to to achieve this look again with the 4.1 update?

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Could you show a screenshot of your node setup and material settings

Since you called the file "4.1 bug", maybe this is a bug and it should rather be reported. The thing is, in Cycles negative Strength values for the Emission shader still work - but not in EEVEE. And this is just the case for the Emission node, negative values for all light sources (Point, Sun, Spot, Area) still work in both Cycles and EEVEE.

Hello Gordon I actually did report this
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/122821
and was told it was a fix for this problem
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/3f778150a93d073c5a433c92a571f7c80cd0a53a
on the second note I tried using other shaders before to see if anything else would produce the effect and got the same result (though I may have missed some.)
As for giving more information I'll submit some screenshots of my node setup shortly.
